# Allowing /clientevent/process url

Tags: sitecore-forms

`/clientevent/process` currently throws *Object reference not set exception* with the stacktrace as shown below.

Is there any configuration like IgnoreUrlPrefixes that need to be configured to throw a 404 error rather than a 500?

> [NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an
>   object.]
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Data.Wrappers.WrappedRendering.get_UniqueId() +3
>   Sitecore.Forms.Mvc.Attributes.FormErrorHandlerAttribute.OnException(ExceptionContext
>   filterContext) +109
>   System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeExceptionFilters(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, IList`1 filters, Exception exception) +173
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass21.b__19(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState) +1133
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +168
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.BeginInvokeAction(ControllerContext
>   controllerContext, String actionName, AsyncCallback callback, Object
>   state) +454
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.b__1c(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +41
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +66
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +168
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state) +901
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +169
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +711
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.b__4(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState, ProcessRequestState innerState) +93 
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallBeginDelegate(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object callbackState) +67
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResultBase`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout) +169
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state) +555
>   System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +1028    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +134

Comment: Does that path exist as items in your tree?

Comment: No it doesn't exist as such. But when I access /clientevents/process or /form, I am running into this issue.

Comment: Was a solution to this ever found? I also have this issue (or very similar) when upgrading from 8.0 to 8.2.